# How to implement the following linux command in Java

Tags: java, linux, unix

How to implement it in Java?

```
grep "Exception" /home/admin/logs/common-error.log |sort |uniq -c |sort -nr
```

I only know what does this command mean, while have no idea about how to implement it in Java...

Many thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to implement it in Java? Why can't you run the pipeline in a shell, and then read its output?

Comment: Just a question on the interview...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run it as a process within Java as shown below, but remember this will only work in Linux or Mac environments.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("grep \"Exception\" /home/admin/logs/common-error.log |sort |uniq -c |sort -nr
");
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
 output.append(line + "\n");
}
System.out.println(output.toString());
```

Comment: I was confused about this interview question itself. Now I got it, thank you! It helps :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample,

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");                                                                                                                                                     

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Detail can be found here [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)).